# Add MongoDB Sink Connector on docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a Ubuntu machine, where I followed this steps in order to run Confluent Platform with docker.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html

I can produce and subscribe to messages just fine.

I'm trying to add a `MongoDB Sink Connector`, in order to sync data with a mongo database.

1. I've downloaded this zip file https://www.confluent.io/hub/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb
2. I've edited the `etc/MongoDbSinkConnector.properties` file with the correct mongo endpoint
3. I've uploaded the zip to my Ubuntu machine
4. I've created a file `Dockerfile` with the following content

   ```
   FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base

   COPY hpgrahsl-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.4.0.zip /tmp/hpgrahsl-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.4.0.zip

   RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt /tmp/hpgrahsl-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.4.0.zip
   ```
5. I've executed the following command `docker build . -t my-custom-image:1.0.0`

   ```
   Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.03MB
   Step 1/3 : FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base
    ---> 8fe065fffe44
   Step 2/3 : COPY hpgrahsl-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.4.0.zip /tmp/hpgrahsl-kafka-connect-mongodb- 
   1.4.0.zip
    ---> Using cache
    ---> ed2e4ec7ff97
   Step 3/3 : RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt /tmp/hpgrahsl-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.4.0.zip
    ---> Using cache
    ---> 034f82e2e136
   Successfully built 034f82e2e136
   Successfully tagged my-custom-image:1.0.0
   ```

Am I missing something? My mongo does not get updated

Do I have to edit `docker-compose.yml` also?

How do I debug this connector, does it have logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run Kafka Connect under Docker (including with the `cp-kafka-connect-base`) image it is usually in *distributed* mode. To create a connector configuration in this mode you use a REST call; it won't load the configuration from a flat file (per *standalone* mode).

You can either launch the container that you've created and then manually create the connector with a REST call, or you can automate that REST call - here's an example of doing it within a Docker Compose:

```yaml
  kafka-connect-01:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.0
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:29092"
[…]
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        #
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.4.0

        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 

        #
        echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on localhost ⏳"
        while : ; do
          curl_status=$$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://localhost:8083/connectors)
          echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$curl_status " (waiting for 200)"
          if [ $$curl_status -eq 200 ] ; then
            break
          fi
          sleep 5 
        done
        echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating connector"
        curl -s -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/mongo-connector/config \
            -d '{
              [… connector JSON config goes here …]
        }'
        sleep infinity
```

References:

- https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-kafka-connect-ksqldb-and-kafka/
- https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-connect/docker/

Comment: hi robin, i've actually just solved this, after checking your blog and videos on youtube. thank you very much :D

Comment: https://rmoff.net/2020/06/19/how-to-install-connector-plugins-in-kafka-connect/